# Regex to get parameters of Embed

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

CODE:

```
var a = [
 /<b\>(.*?)<\/b\>/ig,
 /<i\>(.*?)<\/i\>/ig, 
 /<u\>(.*?)<\/u\>/ig,
 /<br\/\>(.*?)/ig,
 /<embed(.*?)/ig
 ];

 var b = [
   '[b]$1[/b]',
   '[i]$1[/i]',
   '[u]$1[/u]',
   '\r',
   '[flash($2,$3)]$1[/flash]'
  ];

   for (var i =0;i<a.length;i++) {
    ele = ele.replace(a[i], b[i]);
     }
```

HTML:

```
<embed 
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/v/DM0vRHUu6eI"
 width="500" 
 height="500" 
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 wmode="transparent" 
 quality="high" 
 scale="exactfit">
```

What I would like to get is

`$1` starting position of [flash]

`$2` width parameter

`$3` height parameter

The beginning of the code is to change all html elements into BBCodes. Should I go about the regex different in the embed regex? See example here for a better understand!

http://jsbin.com/ajeqog/2/edit

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this at all? And in your demo, why do you have similar markup in both the page, and as a string in JavaScript? Where exactly is the source coming from?

Comment: you ... do know jquery can select elements and attributes, right? you need to rethink practically your entire code, to be honest. using regexes for this when you're already using jquery makes NO sense and requires a ton of extra effort.

Comment: @CrazyTrain it's just a visual to get the markup then change it to bbcode, once the code is done it will implement that page into the textarea the whole code isn't done I need to get the regex first.

Comment: What's up with the downvotes, do you not think if I was going to make it this easy I would do it with jQuery alone,jQuery doesn't have the capability to do what I want. So mess off with what I want with regex that was my question. not what you think! I don't use jQuery for everything so I don't have to use a library. First off it will grab the html of a document, or what the user copies into the textarea, then place it inside of a textarea. It needs to change the html into bbcodes NOT HTML. god people just love to downvote for no apparent reason.

Comment: EasyBB, if you didn't want people to tell you jQuery could do what you're asking, you shouldn't tag your question with jQuery.  As is, you brought JQuery into this, not us.

Comment: I added jQuery as it does return more users to view, plus I don't mind using it for say selectors and so forth. But there are a lot of functions in jQuery that I do not use. That was just my point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out - jQuery has EXACTLY what you're looking for, if you know the lesser used variants, like the fact that `$('<b>Hello</b>')` parses and returns the HTML you've passed it.  So you're looking for something like this:

```
var str = '<b>Hello</b><br/><i>World</i><br/><u>I hate you!</u><br/><ul><li>Good</li><li>Goodbye</li><li>Good afternoon</li><li>Good marrow</li></ul> <embed pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/DM0vRHUu6eI" width="500" height="500" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" quality="high" scale="exactfit">';

var convertible = {
    B: function(loc){
        return '[b]' + convertToBBCode($(loc).html()) + '[/b]';
    }
    , I: function(loc){
        return '[i]' + convertToBBCode($(loc).html()) + '[/i]';
    }
};
function convertToBBCode(str){
    if (!str || str == undefined) return '';
    var toReturn = '';
    $('<div>'+str+'</div>').contents().each(function(){
        if (this.tagName == undefined) toReturn += this.nodeValue;
        else if (convertible[this.tagName] != undefined)
            toReturn += convertible[this.tagName](this);
        else 
            toReturn += $(this).html(convertToBBCode(this.innerHTML))[0].outerHTML;
    });
    return toReturn;
}

$('textarea').val(convertToBBCode(str));
```

I haven't done the whole thing, because I think it's pretty self evident what's being done.  The hardest part for you is the EMBED, which becomes easy as pie:

```
    , EMBED: function(loc){
        var l = $(loc);
        return '[flash(' + l.attr('width') + ',' + l.attr('height') + ')]' + l.attr('src') + '[/flash]';
    }
```

You can see a partial solution [here, in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzuwS/1/).

Remember, You should very rarely be using regular expressions to parse a Context sensitive language like HTML.  You should also listen when people tell you you're probably approaching a problem wrong - if you have a valid reason for your non-traditional approach, you should spell out to us where you think the traditional approach fails.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the understanding. I get angered by those darn downvotes. And when I was reading on how to manifest html to bbcode I saw you should use Regular Expressions so that is why I started to use that. I'll look more into your code as I never use .each() and rather use the for loop. Thank you Frankie!